# @Version annotation in spring

Tags: jpa

Hey guys how can I use @version annotation but instead of replacing the modified data add a new row with the same identifier and the incremented version in the database.
For example here the id 173 is duplicated the only change is the version, that's my goal.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjByV.png)

Comment: ```@Version``` does not aim to achieve this. Its goal is to prevent from concurrent updating. Thus, the update SQL becomes ```UPDATE ... SET ..., version = version + 1 WHERE id = ? AND version = ?```. If the version of the record in the DB has changed, then no row is updated (and an exception is thrown)

Comment: If you're using hibernate as the underlying JPA impl, take a look at https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/ it does what I think you're after.

Comment: Is there any way I can achieve this goal ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Version` is intended for optimistic locking and should not be used for this.

As [Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229743/taylor) commented you can use Hibernate Envers for something really similar. It will result in a separate table containing all your versions, while the main table that you map your entity to still has only the current version.

If you want all these entities to be actually in the same table you should just make the existing id plus an additional version field the id and then copy the entity and update the version before changing it. *Version* field here means a normal probably numeric field that you use as version it must not be annotated with `@Version`.

If you really want to abuse the `@Version` attribute you could create a trigger on the underlying table that creates a new row on every update.